# Google Apps Script Webhook to Save any Input to a Google Drive File (JSON?)

Tags: google-apps-script, web-applications, google-drive-api

I would like to use Apps Script to save anything sent to the Web App URL as a text file on Google Drive. I believe that this should be done with a basic doGet and doPost setup.

If I could get the file saved with a unique filename, that'd be great, but it's not important. I thought there would be a tutorial somewhere about this, but I can't seem to find it at all.

Comment: Will the data sent to the web app come by way of a URL parameter (doGet) or in the request body (doPost)?

Answer (score 1):

## A basic workflow of what you need to do:

- Create a [WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) with a `doGet()` function
- Retrieve the data your application has sent to your WebApp url with `e.parameter` or `e.parameters` - depending on either it's a single string or an array, your retrieved data should be assigned to certain key
- If the key is called "test" and your data is passed as `https://script.google.com/a/XXX/macros/s/XXX/exec?test=Hello`, you should query for `myString = e.parameter.name`
- Create a text file on your drive with `DriveApp.createFile(name, content, mimeType)` -  specifying a `name` of your choice, passing the retrieved string as `content` and chosing [mimeType](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/mime-type) `PLAIN_TEXT`